# Executing a non-interactive program from a Windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a Windows service that wakes up every 20 seconds and looks at a report queue and will execute a program based on what's in the report queue. If I run the report program independently then it work with no problem. If it's executed from the service I receive the following error in the event log...

```
Application: cqrAbandonedCallsRpt.exe 
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: 
        The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
            Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException Stack: at 
               CallQueueReport.cqrAbandonedCallsRpt.Main(System.String[])
```

There no additional information in the log. I have commented out all the code in the main function and I still receive the error. Also the service is running under an administrator account.

Any idea what would be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the problem isn't actually in the `Main` method but in the type initializer for the class which contains `Main`.  Perhaps in a static field that gets initialized inline in the class?  Something like this?:

```
class Program
{
    // this...
    static string someValue = SomeObject.FetchSomeValue();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // no code here
    }
}
```

The `TypeInitializationException` you're seeing is likely obscuring (possibly as an inner exception) the actual error that's taking place.  Try removing all of the inline initialization code from the class and initializing values as a first step in `Main()`, then you can wrap the initialization code in a `try/catch` and log the actual error that's taking place, so you can meaningfully address the root cause.

(In my experience, `TypeInitializationException` is just a short way of saying `ThereIsTooMuchUnvalidatedLogicAtTheClassLevelAndYouShouldPutItInAMethodException`.)

Comment: Thanks, I commented out all of the static variables and walked down until I found the problem.